# Не работает вывод json-строки

Tags: jquery, json

При загрузке страницы пытаюсь отобразить содержимое .json файла, но в вывод попадает строка `[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]`. Что я делаю не так?

```
<div id="airport-list"></div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $.getJSON('/json/airports.json', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, field){
                $('#airport-list').append(field + '' );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Нужно вытащить значение поля **ru** в поле **name_translations** в строке, которая имеет следующий вид:

```
{
  "code":"SVO",
  "name":"Sheremetyevo International",
  "coordinates":{"lon":37.416573,"lat":55.966324},
  "time_zone":"Europe/Moscow",
  "name_translations":{
    "en":"Sheremetyevo International",
    "de":"Moskau-Scheremetjewo",
    "zh-CN":"谢列梅捷沃机场",
    "ru":"Шереметьево",
    "tr":"Şeremetyevo Uluslararası Havalimanı",
    "it":"Sheremetyevo",
    "fr":"Sheremetyevo",
    "es":"Sheremetyevo",
    "th":"สนามบินนานาชาติเชเรเมเตียโว"
  },
  "country_code":"RU",
  "city_code":"MOW"
}
```

Comment: что представляет из себя `field`? приведите пример возвращаемых данных

Comment: @Igor да без понятия. Взял пример [здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getjson.asp). Мне нужно вытащить значение поля **ru** в поле **name_translations**. Пример объекта добавил в пост.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере по ссылке из Вашего комментария, итерация происходит по свойствам объекта, значения этих свойств и передаются в анонимный обработчик `each`. В коде же вопроса, `data` - это массив, а `field` - объекты - элементы массива.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

```
 $('#airport-list').append(field["name_translations"]["ru"] + '' );
```